# Google merchant center multiple prices due to VAT for different countries in the same feed

Tags: xml, google-shopping, google-merchant-center

We have a XML-feed with out products for the Google Merchant Center. We are defining products like this:

```
<item>
    <title>My Product</title>
    <link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com.html/product.html]]></link>
    <g:id><![CDATA[12345678]]></g:id>
    <g:price>198.00 EUR</g:price>
    <g:sale_price>149.00 EUR</g:sale_price>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    ...
    <g:shipping>
        <g:country>DE</g:country>
        <g:service><![CDATA[Shipping Germany]]></g:service>
        <g:price>0.00 EUR</g:price>
    </g:shipping>
    <g:shipping>
        <g:country>AT</g:country>
        <g:service><![CDATA[Shipping Austria]]></g:service>
        <g:price>9.49 EUR</g:price>
    </g:shipping>
</item>
```

Now due to the different hight of VAT, we want to have different prices for each country. Whats the way to do it? I was hoping for something like:

```
<g:price>
    <g:country>DE</g:country>
    <g:value>198.00 EUR</g:value>
</g:price>
<g:price>
    <g:country>AT</g:country>
    <g:value>199.66 EUR</g:value>
</g:price>
```

but coulnd't find anything like that. Is the only way really to repeat the whole product with a different price? Or do you have to create a different feed? The language is always the same so re-transmitting the whole product-details like description is a bit like doubly doubled.